# Efficient Factorization for Family of Matrix Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I am looking for an efficient solution to the following problem
$$
A+\lambda I = b 
\tag{1}
$$
where $A\in\mathbf{S}^{n}$ is a symmetric matrix with nonzero eigenvalues, $b\in\mathbf{R}^n$ is fixed, $I$ is the $n$ dimensional identity matrix, and $\lambda$ is variable. I will need to solve the above problem for multiple instances of $\lambda$ so an efficient factorization is desirable. I have considered using the Woodbury matrix identity for $(A+\lambda I)^{-1}$, which gives us

$$(A+\lambda I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda}I-\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\lambda A^{-1} - I\right)^{-1}$$

but I am not sure if this helps. Another thing I considered is simultaneous diagonalization of A and I, that is writing $A=Q^T D Q$, where $Q\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is a unitary matrix, and $D\in\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix. This would give us

$$(A+\lambda I)^{-1}b = Q^T(D +\lambda I)^{-1}\left(Qb\right)$$

which would simplify our solution by only requiring a single diagonalization, a single matrix multiplication, $Q b$, and a matrix multiplication for each instance of $\lambda$ that I solve (1). However, really, I am looking to take advantage of LU decomposition if possible. Does anyone know if there is a way to use LU decomposition here? Thanks!

Comment: In general, you cannot update a triangular factorisation of a diagonally shifted matrix in less than $O(n^3)$ steps; see, e.g., [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585713/qr-factorization-of-a-special-structured-matrix). This, of course, is not the case, if you have already the eigen-decomposition of $A$. If your $A$ is sparse and you consider solving your systems iteratively, you can consider recycling already computed Krylov subspaces as they are invariant w.r.t. scalar shifts (this, however, works only if the right-hand sides are fixed).

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate what you mean by computing the Krylov subspaces to solve? Everything is constant save $\lambda$. Thanks!

Comment: For this approach, you might have a look, e.g., on [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S1064827596304563).